# R, pins and AzureStor: unused argument (azure_storage_progress_bar = progress)

Tags: r, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-machine-learning-service, pins

```
pins 1.0.1
AzureStor 3.7.0
```

I'm getting this error

```
Error in withr::local_options(azure_storage_progress_bar = progress, .local_envir = env) : 
  unused argument (azure_storage_progress_bar = progress)
Calls: %>% ... pin_meta.pins_board_azure -> azure_download -> local_azure_progress
Execution halted
```

when running `pin_read()` in the following code (`pin_list()` works fine)

```
bl_endp_key <- storage_endpoint(endpoint = <endpoint URL>, key =<endpoint key>")
container <- storage_container(endpoint = bl_endp_key, name = <blob name>)
board <- board_azure(container = container, path = "accidentsdata")
cat("Testing pins:\n")
print(board %>% pin_list())
accidents2 <- board %>% pins::pin_read('accidents') %>% as_tibble()
```

My goal is to "pin_read" a dataset located on a Azure Blob Storage from an R script being run from **pipelineJoB (YAML)** including a `command: Rscript script.R ...` and an `environment:` based on a dockerfile installing **R version 4.0.0** (2020-04-24) -- "Arbor Day"

The pipelineJob is being called from an Azure DevOps Pipeline task with `az ml job create <pipelineJob YAML> <resource grp> <aml workspace name>`.

Note: the R script runs fine on my Windows RStudio desktop, with R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up".

I've already tried with

`options(azure_storage_progress_bar=FALSE)` or

`withr::local_options(azure_storage_progress_bar=FALSE)`

but I'm getting the same `unused argument (azure_storage_progress_bar ...` error.

FYI: `local_azure_progress` is defined here [here](https://rdrr.io/github/rstudio/pins/src/R/board_azure.R#sym-local_azure_progress)

Comment: [Progress bar falt with storage_multiupload() even with options(azure_storage_progress_bar=TRUE)](https://github.com/Azure/AzureStor/issues/54)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been filed in [pins](https://github.com/rstudio/pins/issues/624), it seems that is not an AzureStor issue.